Need help formatting CV
So, I'm trying to write my own CV, based on the "Simple Hipster CV"-template. However,  The template creates problems when I change or add entries that makes it exceed it's original size.

Adding a longer email address to the left panes contact info, makes it flow outside the pane instead of continuing on a new line.
The grey background left hand pane suddenly gets a white border on the third page
The tables will jump to a new page or exceed their boundaries when the become to long to fit on the page.



I want:

Contact info in the left pane to continue on a new line when it exceeds the boundaries.
Remove the white border around the grey pane.
Split tables when the exceed the available space on the current page.

Change in code (style and class files are found in the Overleaf template.)
% a mashup of hipstercv, friggeri and twenty cv
% https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv
% https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv

\documentclass[lighthipster]{simplehipstercv}
% available options are: darkhipster, lighthipster, pastel, allblack, grey, verylight, withoutsidebar
% withoutsidebar
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, a4paper]{geometry}


%------------------------------------------------------------------ Variablen

\newlength{\rightcolwidth}
\newlength{\leftcolwidth}
\setlength{\leftcolwidth}{0.23\textwidth}
\setlength{\rightcolwidth}{0.75\textwidth}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{New Simple CV}
\author{\LaTeX{} Ninja}
\date{June 2019}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Start}

\simpleheader{headercolour}{Jack}{Sparrow}{Captain}{white}



%------------------------------------------------

% this has to be here so the paracols starts..
\subsection*{}
\vspace{4em}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\columnratio{0.23}[0.75]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\hbadness5000
%\backgroundcolor{c[1]}[rgb]{1,1,0.8} % cream yellow for column-1 %\backgroundcolor{g}[rgb]{0.8,1,1} % \backgroundcolor{l}[rgb]{0,0,0.7} % dark blue for left margin

\paracolbackgroundoptions

% 0.9,0.9,0.9 -- 0.8,0.8,0.8


\footnotesize
{\setasidefontcolour
\flushright
\begin{center}
    \roundpic{jack.jpg}
\end{center}

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{About me}\\[0.5em]

{\footnotesize
\lorem\lorem\lorem}
\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{personal} \\[0.5em]
Jack Sparrow

nationality: English 

1690

\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Areas of specialization} \\[0.5em]

Privateering ~•~ Bucaneering ~•~ Parler ~•~ Rum

\bigskip



\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Interests}\\[0.5em]

\lorem
\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Interests}\\[0.5em]

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\vspace{4em}

\infobubble{\faAt}{cvgreen}{white}{jack.has.a.long.email.address@sparrow.org}
\infobubble{\faTwitter}{cvgreen}{white}{@sparrow}
\infobubble{\faFacebook}{cvgreen}{white}{Jack Sparrow}
\infobubble{\faGithub}{cvgreen}{white}{sparrow}

\phantom{turn the page}

\phantom{turn the page}
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\switchcolumn

\small
\section*{Short Resumé}

\begin{tabular}{r| p{0.5\textwidth} c}
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back.\lorem\lorem\lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2016--2017}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{Found a secret treasure, lost the ship. \lorem\lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back.\lorem\lorem\lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2016--2017}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{Found a secret treasure, lost the ship. \lorem\lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back.\lorem\lorem\lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2016--2017}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{Found a secret treasure, lost the ship. \lorem\lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back.\lorem\lorem\lorem}{disney.png} \\
    % \cvevent{2016--2017}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{Found a secret treasure, lost the ship. \lorem\lorem}{medal.jpeg}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\section*{Degrees}
\begin{tabular}{r p{0.6\textwidth} c}
    \cvdegree{1710}{Captain}{Certified}{Tortuga Uni \color{headerblue}}{}{disney.png} \\
    \cvdegree{1715}{Bucaneering}{M.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Programming}
\begin{tabular}{r @{\hspace{0.5em}}l}
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{html, css} &  \barrule{0.4}{0.5em}{cvpurple}\\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{\LaTeX} & \barrule{0.55}{0.5em}{cvgreen} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{python} & \barrule{0.5}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{R} & \barrule{0.25}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{javascript} & \barrule{0.1}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\section*{Curriculum}
\begin{tabular}{r| p{0.5\textwidth} c}
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back. \lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2019}{Freelance Pirate}{Bucaneering}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{This and that. The usual, aye?  \lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back. \lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2019}{Freelance Pirate}{Bucaneering}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{This and that. The usual, aye?  \lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back. \lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2019}{Freelance Pirate}{Bucaneering}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{This and that. The usual, aye?  \lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back. \lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2019}{Freelance Pirate}{Bucaneering}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{This and that. The usual, aye?  \lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Certificates \& Grants}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.55\textwidth}}
    1708 & Captain's Certificates \\
    1710 & Travel grant \\
    1715--1716 & Grant from the Pirate's Company
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\section*{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{l | ll}
\textbf{English} & C2 & {\phantom{x}\footnotesize mother tongue} \\
\textbf{French} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{3}{black!30}{1}{\tiny} \\
\textbf{Spanish} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{1}{black!30}{3}{\tiny} \\
\textbf{Italian} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{3}{black!30}{1}{\tiny}
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Publications}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.7\textwidth}}
    1729 & \emph{How I almost got killed by Lady Swan}, Tortuga Printing Press. \\
    1720 & ``Privateering for Beginners'', in: \emph{The Pragmatic Pirate} (1/1720).
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\section*{Talks}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.6\textwidth}}
    Nov. 1726 & ``How I lost my ship (\& and how to get it back)'', at: \emph{Annual Pirate's Conference} in Tortuga, Nov. 1726.
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}






\vfill{} % Whitespace before final footer

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FINAL FOOTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolwidth}
\begin{center}\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont \color{black!70}
{\small Jack Sparrow \icon{\faEnvelopeO}{cvgreen}{} The Black Pearl \icon{\faMapMarker}{cvgreen}{} Tortuga \icon{\faPhone}{cvgreen}{} 0099/333 5647380 \newline\icon{\faAt}{cvgreen}{} \protect\url{jack@sparrow.com}
}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}


Sounds like a good question to the author or maintainer of said package and manual ...

I have posted the issue in the author's repo.
